# Calculate total coverage of circles on map with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, area, circle

I am trying to calculate the total area covered by c.a. 400 Circles of diameter 15Km. The centers of these circles are stored in a column of type geometry:4326 in my database.

Some circles overlap, and I should not add to the total area the overlapping amount twice.

Until now I tried the follwing approach:
1) Use buffer to get circles: select st_buffer(get_location, 15000) from d_station; 
2) Use st_union to join the circles into a single multipoint geometry
3) use st_area to calculate area.

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work, I think because I am not using st_union in the correct way?

Then I found an interesting tutorial [here](http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/10/postgis-training-creating-overlays/), which explains something very similar to what I need. Unfortunately I am not able to get a useful result using this approach either.

How can I obtain a list of circles and merged circles polygons, and then calculate the sum of their areas?

**Update**: I am trying Pierre suggestion. Here the steps I performed:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE pts AS
select ds.id, geo_location as geom from pa.d_station ds

CREATE temporary TABLE circles AS
SELECT id, ST_Buffer(geom, 15000) AS geom FROM pts;

create temporary table circles2 as 
SELECT a.id, pa.ST_DifferenceAgg(a.geogr, b.geogr) geogr
FROM circles a, 
     circles b
WHERE ST_Equals(a.geogr, b.geogr) OR 
   ((ST_Contains(a.geogr, b.geogr) OR 
    ST_Contains(b.geogr, a.geogr) OR 
    ST_Overlaps(a.geogr, b.geogr)) AND 
   (ST_Area(a.geogr) < ST_Area(b.geogr) OR 
    (ST_Area(a.geogr) = ST_Area(b.geogr) AND 
     ST_AsText(a.geogr) < ST_AsText(b.geogr))))
GROUP BY a.id;

select sum(st_area(c2.geogr)) from circles2 c2;
```

But I get a result which is way too low from the expected. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the query you have tried so far that is not working?

Comment: geometry:4326 would use degrees as units. Have you checked the consistency of your SRID?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [PostGIS Addons](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons) and look at the ST_DifferenceAgg() example to remove overlaps:

```
SELECT a.id, ST_DifferenceAgg(a.geom, b.geom) geom
FROM overlappingtable a, 
     overlappingtable b
WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) OR 
      ((ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR 
        ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR 
        ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)) AND 
       (ST_Area(a.geom) < ST_Area(b.geom) OR 
        (ST_Area(a.geom) = ST_Area(b.geom) AND 
         ST_AsText(a.geom) < ST_AsText(b.geom))))
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Then you should be able to easily compute the area.

The method described in the tutorial you mention works for a limited number of polygons.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I updated my question with some code based on your function. I am not sure I am using it right, because the result I get is not very coherent with my use case.

Comment: If you just check the result of removing the overlaps, does it make sense? If you properly remove the overlaps, then it should be straightforward to compute the total area... Are your ds.id unique? radouxju is right. You should construct your buffers, or at least compute the areas, in a projected coordinate system.